Why does matlab/Simulink creates folders?
I am currently doing a lot of unit tests on Simulink and I call all tests one by one in a loop thanks to a command line in a python script:
init_matlab_fcn = "%s -batch \"addpath('%s');" % (matlab_exe,matlab_script)  
init_matlab_fcn += "addpath(genpath('%s'));" % lib_path
init_matlab_fcn += "run('%s');" % param_path
init_matlab_fcn += "Main_Function('%s');exit\"" % sim_project

For each tests I have a folder created with a strange name, i.e: {1D0554CF-E47D-4B42-812E-27531C577960}. These folders appear for each test in the folder containing lib_path and param_path.
Furthermore, there is a dig folder whith inside other folders such as: blob_storage, Cache, etc... and files such as: Cookies, Visited Links... This folder only appeared recently, because since I run tests, it was not supposed to be created.
So I have seen on Matlab/Simulink page that I have to delete all my Temp files/folders but: I must keep some Content ! And I don't know all of them. Do you have any advise for an alternative? Any update since the previous post was published?
I though Matlab support would have given an answer since this issue was pinged, but I did not find the answer...
Also for my own knowledge, why does Matlab create these folders with random titles? why did they appear only after a certain amount of running tests? ( first I was running few tests and it was fine, but when the number of tests got bigger, I started having this issue.)
thanks

I think they're just temporary folders containing build data, so they have junk names because the names don't matter other than being unique, and they only appeared once you'd run several increasingly complex tests because your temp storage filled up and overflowed into the working directory. Agreed this is a pain, I had a similar issue recently and (following that same link) found that cleaning up my %TEMP% directory mitigated the issue

The latest releases do no longer have this issue. Depending on the MATLAB release you are using, installing the latest update might fix it as well.
Have seen this in many R2020b installations. Not sure exactly when the issue was introduced/fixed.
